# Select all records using variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use some of the geography features of SQL Server to figure out what are a customer's closest 10 branch offices. This gets me what I want for one customer:

```
DECLARE @me GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @HH NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT @Me = CustProspLoc, @HH = HHKEY FROM Customers

SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) @HH AS CustOmer, BranchNum, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1), (BranchLoc.STDistance(@me)) / 1609.344) AS Miles, BranchLoc.STDistance(@me)
FROM 
BranchLocations
WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1), (BranchLoc.STDistance(@me)) / 1609.344) < 25  -- less than this many miles
ORDER BY Miles
```

And the result is like this:

```
Customer           BranchNum   Miles
------------------ ---------   ---------------------------
20192              14          1.8
20192              145         4.4
20192              193         5.3
20192              7           6.0
20192              17          7.4
20192              8           7.6
20192              3           8.7
20192              2           9.3
20192              9           9.8
20192              1           10.0
```

But all I get is results for that one Customer...how can I get it for all the customers in the Customers table?

Comment: Can you please share your table structures?

Comment: Two things: 
1) You have your results restricted to TOP 10.  Remove that and see what the results look like. Probably won't matter due to reason #2.
2) You cannot assign multiple values to one variable.

Comment: You have to understand we are using SQL and not some unstructured language where you can have heaps/lists/arrays. I'll try inserting your data into a temp table or CTE and do your customer filtering off of that.

Comment: Instead of using variables, you need to JOIN your Customers table with your BranchLocations table, so that you get all the rows for every customer. So start by dropping the DECLARE statements and the initial SELECT, and add a JOIN to the second SELECT statement, and do your work all in that one SELECT.

Comment: It's just 2 tables, one has BranchNum and the BranchLoc (geography) and the other table has Customer, CustPropLoc  (geography) . Just IDs and geographical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this query

```
Select * from(
SELECT row_number() over(partition by hhkey order by miles) as rownum,   HHKEY as CustOmer, BranchNum, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1), (BranchLoc.STDistance(CustProspLoc)) / 1609.344) AS Miles, BranchLoc.STDistance(CustProspLoc)
FROM 
BranchLocations,Customers
WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),  (BranchLoc.STDistance(CustProspLoc)) / 1609.344) < 25  -- less than this many miles
ORDER BY Miles) as t1 where t1.rownum <= 10
```

Comment: Error message: incorrect syntax near the keyword "over"

Comment: I forgot the `()` of the row_number function. Edited my answer

Comment: @BrianBattles please give a feedback if it still not working.